"Generating code" error when creating a controller using "MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework"
I am getting the following "generating code" error when creating a Controller using "MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework".
I've tried several solutions to similar problem reported online:
Removed .vs folder, cleaned and rebuild, updated the .proj file manually, downgrades packages etc., but none has resolved the issue.
How do I resolve this issue?
